# Users Realms Access or One Public Realm

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-object-server

Let's assume I want to create an app like Instagram. Every user of my app has his own realm file where he keeps his profile data, pictures, likes of pictures and comments.

What if I want to create a wall where are visible latest pictures of all users of my app? Should I somehow access every single realm file of my users and get a picture or maybe should I create one big shared realm file where I will keep all pictures of all my users?

Comment: You should probably not keep blobs in the Realm, only URLs to the images hosted on a server.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep them all in one place.

May be it's better to have offline version also (for the user's convenience) but if you want every single user have online access to the database you should't get pictures from the users only everytime you need them. Imagine if someone is offline what then? Or at least some pictures would get downloaded faster than the others due to some people have better internet than the others.

Comment: it wouldn't be a problem in a case where there will be millions of photos and thousands of users accessing them at the same time?

Comment: In that case you need at least very strong and very orginized server. And may be something like 'micro service architecture' for the server(not sure). And the app also should be orginized preventing from downloading more than user needs at the very moment. May be something downloaded in the background mode. F.i. if the app gets to background it checks for some 'updates' and in case there is something new it downloads it. Or other performance tricks. It needs work. But keeping all of them on a users side is not an option.

Comment: And like it mentioned above there`s usually a good practice to keep only a URL's/file paths in the Realm(same for Core Data).